# Internal Disk is locked and Erasing is taking for ever

Tags: ios, hard-drive, imac, disk-utility

I recently got an iMac they did erase the internal drive for me but for making sure every step is correct I tried to erase the internal drive myself from recovery mode before reinstalling the macOS.
but this time it stocked on erasing exactly on the "Deleting volume" step.
I waited for more than 15 hours but the progress bar was 0%

[image]

then I gave up and restart the iMac, this time I tried to reinstall from recovery mode, but this time in choosing the installation disk, I saw it's grayed and says "this drive is locked".

the only solution I found for the locked drive was to erase it again. but my erasing has problem as I said

Comment: You need to enable "Show All Disks" in Disk Utility, you didn't erase the correct one.

Comment: Can you get into Internet Recovery? If so, once you are in Disk Utility, then press Cmd/2 which will show the actual hard drive rather than just the volumes & you can then Erase the drive instead. You can't do this from local Recovery.

Comment: @At0mic I dont know how to thank you man!!! I'm in installation process right now thanks to you

Answer (score 1):

thanks to my friend @At0mic who commented on my question.
by choosing "Show All devices" I was able to erase the parent disk and that went smoothly
and now I'm in the installation process :)))